# Show object type in Firefox DOM inspector

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, firefox-developer-tools

Some time ago, I used Firebug to inspect the DOM of a webpage in Firefox. It showed me the *type* of the objects (the name of the constructor, I guess).

Today, Firebug is gone. For firefox' DOM tab, everything is displayed as `Object` only. This slows me down a lot, I have to look into the objects to see what type they have.

Is there any way to restore the "good old firebug behaviour"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a missing feature in the Firefox devtools.  There's a general "[firebug gaps](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806)" bug that tries to list all of these.  This particular problem is covered in [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1337701).

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the link and even mentioning it at the bugzilla discussion. :-)

Comment: The referenced bug is not the right one, because it refers to the output of `console.log()`. The question here refers to the display of the [DOM Property Viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DOM_Property_Viewer).

Comment: Thanks.  I think I also found another one somewhere referring to the results of evaluation in the console.

Answer (score 1):

A direct comparison (Firefox 53.0 vs. Firebug 2.0.19) shows that the object types *are* displayed:

[image: Object type display in the Firefox DevTools' DOM Property Viewer in comparison to Firebug's DOM panel]

The display only misses the parameters or properties in some cases, which is already [filed as a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1267235). Besides that the [DOM Property Viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DOM_Property_Viewer) also [has some other bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?list_id=13552412&resolution=---&query_format=advanced&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20DOM).

As Tom mentioned, there's also a [general bug listing all gaps related to Firebug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806). And there are also some display issues regarding objects within the console panel like [some properties not being displayed in logged objects](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1337701), as mentioned by Tom.

And if there's some issue in comparison to Firebug's UI which is not filed yet, you should [report a bug for it blocking the "Firebug gaps" bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools&blocked=991806).